# Get normal of bezier curve in 2D

Tags: curve, bezier

I'm trying to wrap text in bezier curve and following tutorial from this link, http://www.planetclegg.com/projects/WarpingTextToSplines.html

I get Derivative by this code:

```
function Derivative(x0,x1,x2,t)
{
   var mt = 1-t;
   var a = mt * mt; 
   var b = mt * t * 2; 
   var c = t * t; 
   var result=a * x0 + b * x1 + c * x2;
   return result;
}
```

So i calcu Normal with this code:

```
function Normal(x0,x1,x2,y0,y1,y2,t) 
{      
  var dx = Derivative(x0,x1,x2,t);     
  var dy = Derivative(y0,y1,y2,t);  

  var q = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
  return { x: -dy/q, y: dx/q };
};
```

So this is result: somthing wrong but i don't know where.

[image: See image]

Thanks you all!

Comment: The Derivative() function is basically evaluating a quadratic Bezier curve with (x0,y0), (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)  as the control points. So, if you think it is for computing the derivative of another curve, then most likely the curve in your mind is in fact a cubic Bezier curve. If this is the case, you will have to pass in x0=P1x-P0x, x1=P2x-P1x and x2=P3x-P2x (same for y0,y1, y2 values) where P0,P1, P2 and P3 are control points of the cubic Bezier curve.

Comment: Actually cubic -> quadratic is P0, 2/3 P0->P1, 2/3 P2->p1, P2;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "what I want" image looks a lot like my [bezierjs documentation](http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#normal), so: you have the right idea (take the derivative to get the tangent vector, then rotate to get the normal), but make sure to get those derivatives right.

If you're using quadratic Bezier curves, consisting of three 2d points P1, P2 and P3, then the Bezier function is:

```
P1 * (1-t)² + P2 * 2 * (1-t)t + P3 * t²
```

and the derivative (written in but one of many ways) is:

```
P1 * (2t-2) + (2*P3-4*P2) * t + 2 * P2
```

The code you show as derivative computation is actually the regular quadratic Bezier function, so that's going to give you rather wrong results. Update the code to the correct derivative, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Pomax's answer is all you need, but if you care for a bit of code here are some util methods implemented in Javascript:

```
// these methods are only for quadratic curves

// p1: {x,y} start point
// pc: {x,y} control point    
// p2: {x,y} end point
// t: (float between 0 and 1) time in the curve

getPointAt(t, p1, pc, p2) {
    const x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p1.x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * pc.x + t * t * p2.x
    const y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p1.y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * pc.y + t * t * p2.y

    return { x, y };
}

getDerivativeAt(t, p1, pc, p2) {
    const d1 = { x: 2 * (pc.x - p1.x), y: 2 * (pc.y - p1.y) };
    const d2 = { x: 2 * (p2.x - pc.x), y: 2 * (p2.y - pc.y) };

    const x = (1 - t) * d1.x + t * d2.x;
    const y = (1 - t) * d1.y + t * d2.y;

    return { x, y };
}

getNormalAt(t, p1, pc, p2) {
    const d = getDerivativeAt(t, p1, pc, p2);
    const q = sqrt(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y);

    const x = -d.y / q;
    const y = d.x / q;

    return { x, y };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lupq8ejm/1/

[image: Quadratic curve with normals]